# Authenticate to Jira/Bamboo using OAuth in Swift/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, oauth, jira, bamboo

I am trying to authenticate to my Bamboo application using OAuth.
I have set up the Application link in Bamboo and gave it a consumer key and public key and used 2-legged OAuth.

I want to be able to authenticate without the callback telling the user to type their credentials in.

I am new to OAuth so I am struggling to understand all the online tutorials.

How would I do this from Swift/Objective-C?

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try these tutorials: http://oauth.net/code/ (scroll down for Objective-C), http://davidquail.com/2009/12/07/oauth-authorization-callback-on-the-iphone-with-webview/